# How can I use C1DateEdit in C1TrueDBGrid?

Tags: componentone

I need bind DateTime to C1TrueDBGrid and allow to edit  the value .
the default control is DateTime Picker , but I need edit hour and miniute .

SO , How can I use C1DateEdit in C1TrueDBGrid ?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion would be to set the: [`EnableDateTimeEditor`](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/nethelp/c1truedbgrid/#!XMLDocuments/Ref/html/P_C1_Win_C1TrueDBGrid_C1DataColumn_EnableDateTimeEditor.htm) property to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

`C1TrueDBGrid.Columns("DateColumnName").Editor = C1DateEdit`